# How to grant SYSDBA access to users on Oracle Cloud v19c

Tags: oracle

It seems that you can't grant SYSDBA access to users on oracle cloud. I am using v19c, when trying to alter roles through the web "Database Actions" interface, the only roles I see are; CDB_DBA DBA LBAC_DBA PDB_DBA. How can I make a user SYSDBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can't. You need to use PDBADMIN user or PDB_DBA role for such things: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/exadata/doc/eccmanagingdatabases.html

Also there is a very useful document:
[Known Issues for Oracle Database Exadata Express Cloud Service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbk/access-and-privileges.html#GUID-341D61B3-8206-480B-BF94-D1F806487B54)
It gives some more internal info about cloud access and privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the PDB_DBA role for the ADMIN user. There is actually no PDBADMIN user. What I am trying to do is install utPLSQL on oracle cloud. This is turning out to be more difficult then I envisaged. There is a stackoverflow question relating to this, if you have any insight it woulld be appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694500/installing-utplsql-in-oracle-cloud#comment118838974_66694500

Comment: Actually that all depends on the kind of database you are using in the Oracle Cloud. For anything autonomous (ADB/ATP/ADW), you just cannot have DBA access: that is the whole point of having your database managed for you. The highest privileged account is ADMIN that lets you do essential maintenance.